# tinyXml how to add an element

Tags: c++, ubuntu, tinyxml

I have the following:

```
TiXmlDocument doc;
TiXmlDeclaration * decl = new TiXmlDeclaration( "1.0", "utf-8", "");
doc.LinkEndChild( decl );
TiXmlElement * root = new TiXmlElement( "Value" );  
TiXmlElement * element = new TiXmlElement( "number" );  
root->LinkEndChild( element);  

TiXmlText * text = new TiXmlText( "5" );  
element->LinkEndChild( text );
```

IT IS OK LIKE THIS? I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE the .xml like:

```
<Value>
<number>5</number>
</Value>
```

THX!

my question is if i can have a int value as a string. if it;s ok if i send in that way the xml file? or is there a way to specify that 5 is an int and not a text?

Comment: did you try running the code ? did you face any *specific* problem?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the "root" variable.

Comment: my question is if i can have a int value as a string. if it;s ok if i send in that way the xml file? or is there a way to specify that 5 is an int and not a text?

Comment: Honestly, I can't understand your question. A XML file is just a text file, a sequence of character. There's no integer in a xml file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create xml using tinyxml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016862/create-xml-using-tinyxml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to append a node containing an integer value, this integer has first be transformed to a string. You can do this with a variety of functions, but I prefer `snprintf` (others might differ :) )

Consider the following example:

```
int five = 5;
char buf[256];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", five); // transforms the integer to a string
TiXmlText * text = new TiXmlText( buf );  
element->LinkEndChild( text );
```

Comment: I see.Thx. Does TiXmlText() expacts a string value inside the brackets?

Comment: Yes, it does. It expects either a `char` or a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, a `TiXmlText` node is text. You can send a textual representation of an integer, but you can't treat the node's value as an integer, unless you convert it yourself.

In summary, it's up to you to convert from whatever type to text when you store it in the `TiXmlText` node, and then back from text to whatever type when you retrieve it.