# TinyXml SetAttribute value without quot

Tags: tinyxml

I have used tinyxml to produce one xml.
The xml is as below

```
<Start ver="1.0">
<Inner>
<id val="12345t678"/>
<txn val="123"/>
<exm val="2"/>
</Inner> 
</Start>
```

But i wanted this exm val to come as integer (without quote).

```
like <exm val=2>
```

Any suggestion ..
Regards

Answer (score 0):

@Rajesh Swain 
   Here is Mark Bullock's Experts Exchange response to the same question you posted a year ago.

When value is an attribute you have to use quotes: value="123"

When value is an element you don't have to use quotes:

Answer (score 0):

@Rajesh Swain and anybody who is interested in using tinyxml , please read the
example code here in Constantinius answer's

[tinyXml how to add an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017672/tinyxml-how-to-add-an-element)